# Declaring non-default JNDI connection for JPA access in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

The following snippet works in Play for Scala:

```
class MyDAO @Inject() (jpaApi: JPAApi) {      

  @Transactional
  def someMethod = {
    jpaApi.withTransaction {   // ....
```

In `application.conf` I defined `db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS` and `jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit`.

Now, I also need to define another JNDI connection `db.another.jndiName=AnotherDS` with `jpa.another=anotherPersistenceUnit`.

Where the `persistence.xml` is:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HANAColumnStoreDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="anotherPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>AnotherDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HANAColumnStoreDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

How to inject `AnotherDS` in the application so it can be used with JPAApi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify multiple JPA configurations in `application.conf`:

```
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
... // other configuration for db.default
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit

db.another.jndiName=AnotherDS
... // other configuration for db.another
jpa.another=anotherPersistenceUnit
```

In your DAO, inject `JPAApi` as you're currently doing. Use [`JPAApi#em(String)`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/java/play/db/jpa/JPAApi.html#em-java.lang.String-) to get the `EntityManager` for a specific persistence unit name:

```
class MyDAO @Inject() (jpaApi: JPAApi) {

  def someMethodWithDefault = {
    val em = jpaApi.em("default") // em is an EntityManager
    jpaApi.withTransaction {
      ...
    }
  }

  def someMethodWithAnother = {
    val em = jpaApi.em("another") // em is an EntityManager
    jpaApi.withTransaction {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Also, the `@Transactional` annotation is unnecessary if you're using `JPAApi#withTransaction`.